# Replace all occurrences of a character on every line excepting commented lines

Tags: regex, replace, wsh, emeditor

I need a way to replace all characters "y" and "r" with "n" on every line in a file EXCEPT lines starting with ">" using [EmEditor](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjWzZ2zle7XAhVJP5oKHdnDBpAQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.emeditor.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw15nyGrOIzfliHTXigagGAm)'s built-in Regex++ (version 1.57 by Dr John Maddock). This regex flavor [supports](http://boost.cowic.de/rc/pdf/regex.pdf) only fixed length lookbehind and also doesn't have all advanced .NET enhancements for regexes.

Here is an example input file:

```
> A header containing "y" and "r"    
tttttrtagggaar-rrgatctg--gcctrtcc---cacyaayygggayyyaggc
```

And here is desired result of replacement:

```
> A header containing "y" and "r"  
tttttntagggaan-nngatctg--gcctntcc---cacnaanngggannnaggc
```

It would be ideal to be able to perform such replacement in a single step. But currently I'm completely stuck at finding even a two-step or script-based solution (EmEditor [allows writing Windows Scripting Host macroses](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/extensibility/scriptable-macros/)). I know that I can find all non-commented lines with regex `^(?!>).*$`, but haven't found a way to select them in order to perform the replacement `r|y` → `n` in the selection only (using the corresponding option in the ["Replace" dialog](https://1z9j8fz5fww49iaje1itey71-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/emeditor13_replace_regularexpression.png)).

Is there a way to achieve this with EmEditor?

Comment: How about: Find `^[^>].*?\K[yr]`, Replace `n`, and click replace all as many times as wanted?

Comment: @Toto It works, but may require 20-50 clicking in my case what is undesirable. But thanks for introducing `\K` for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since EmEditor default regex engine is Boost, you can do this:

Find: `^>.*|([yr])`

Replace with: `(?1:n:$0)`

Note: multi-line mode should be on.

Comment: Unfortunately this regex produces an error: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXW4s.png) (multi-line mode is turned on).

Comment: Thank you, the updated solution works! Although I have no idea what `(?1:n:$0)` means. Could you give a reference/explanation for this syntax?

Comment: The new method works also with multi-line mode turned off.

Comment: It's a conditional statement which means if group one's captured replace matched part with `n` otherwise with whole matching part.